# Passing & and &mut through macro matched types

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I've boiled down an issue I'm seeing into [this snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/bn8vrv6hE):

```
macro_rules! test_impl {
    (&mut $_:ty) => { 1 };
    (&$_:ty) => { 2 };
    ($_:ty) => { 3 };
}

macro_rules! test {
    ($val: literal, $($t:ty), *) => { ($val $(, test_impl!($t))*) }
}

fn main() {
    // I'm expecting (0, 3, 2, 1) here...
    println!("{:?}", test!(0, f64, &f64, &mut f64));
}
```

When ends up printing out:

```
(0, 3, 3, 3)
```

It seems like the reference and mutable parts of the `t` type aren't getting passed through. Am I understanding how this works wrong? Is there a way to pass the "reference/mut-ness" through the outer `test!` macro and match it in `test_impl!`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Quoting [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/macros-by-example.html#transcribing):

> When forwarding a matched fragment to another macro-by-example, matchers in the second macro will see an opaque AST of the fragment type. The second macro can't use literal tokens to match the fragments in the matcher, only a fragment specifier of the same type. The `ident`, `lifetime`, and `tt` fragment types are an exception, and can be matched by literal tokens.

You cannot work around that with declarative macros: proc macros are able to remove those invisible fragments (they're represented as [groups](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/proc_macro/struct.Group.html) with [invisible delimiters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/proc_macro/enum.Delimiter.html#variant.None)), but `macro_rules!` cannot. The only way is to not capture them from the beginning and match them with `tt`. Matching complex fragments, like `ty`, can be hard and require [tt munching](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros/patterns/tt-muncher.html).

Comment: Thanks! I was able to find [a solution](https://godbolt.org/z/9fxcv1xM3) based on the tt munching concept